# Yeoman angular project without jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying to use yeoman to scaffold a new angular project, but I notice that a lot of the dependencies import jquery.  Bootstrap forces a jquery import, even though I only plan on using the bootstrap css, and I will be using ng-strap instead of the jquery based bootstrap.js.  Similarly, the karma dependency seems to also require jquery.

Anyone have any tips or best practices on using yeoman to create an angular project with boostrap css and a test framework that doesn't require importing jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman only creates the boilerplate for your project.
After you have used the (I expect) "yo angular" to generate the boilerplate, you are free to edit the dependencies, using bower install/uninstall or edit bower.js.
You may also edit out the import of jquery in you index.html

But why is it a problem that you have jquery in your project? You don't need to use is just because it is there, but you still need it if your third party frameworks depend on it.

Comment: Ok I think my question is then a bower question instead of a yeoman question.  I have a bower.json file with dependencies:  

    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.2.6",
        "bootstrap": "~3.0.3"
    } 
but when I run grunt bower-install it automatically injects 

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
into my index.html along with the bootstrap.js.  Is there a bower dependency that will only make it inject the css and not the javascript?

Comment: Your could just do the injection into index.html you self, and not run "grunt bower-install", then you are in complete control :-)